# FullCalendar: is there still a viewRender event hook?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I need something like the `viewRender` event in order to persist the user's state. I'm building a UI where users will frequently jump in and out of the calendar, so preserving their view/range is essential for a pleasant experience. Does this exist in v5? The last mention I can find of it is from [v3](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/viewRender).

The only workaround I can think of right now is a direct click handler on every view control element, or a very heavy-handed MutationObserver. This is a React app so either one is going to be super awkward.

Thank you!

### Edit 2021-02-11:

I looked at the available [view render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-render-hooks) but none of them address my problem. What I need is an event that will fire whenever the view *state* changes, including clicking between weeks/months/etc., so that I can persist the date range the user most recently viewed *as well as* the view they had selected.

`viewDidMount` is the closest to what I need, but it does not fire when the date range changes.

### Edit 2021-05-26:

Another problem with using `viewDidMount` is that using it to enact side-effects is a bit overeager. The hook gets called whether or not the user has actually done anything, and the default view always gets passed as `view` inside the View Object. So there's no way to tell whether this mount event contains data I should persist or not.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-render-hooks

Comment: @ADyson I did see those, but they don't work for my use-case unfortunately. I didn't do a great job explaining the date range aspect - please see edit.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. Probably your best bet for monitoring date range changes is to add a (fake) event source using the event-as-a-function technique (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) - the callback function receives the start and end of the visible range. So you can log it from there. Only disadvantage is it's separate to knowing when the view type changes. But perhaps if you persist the view type and the date range as two distinct pieces of data it won't be a problem.

Comment: Separate is fine, as long as I can persist both of them reliably. Thanks!

Comment: @ADyson I'm back on this project after a while and I'm still having trouble with persisting the view...I'm not sure if it's possible to distinguish between the initial mount event and the user clicking between views. Currently the initial mount is clobbering the persisted view option. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ADyson nevermind! Passing the `initialView` prop instead of `defaultView` fixed the issue with `viewDidMount`. Thanks!